# Change how google form inserts data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google form which collects data and inserts it to a google sheet horizontally, let say from A2:F2. I want to transform this data to vertical so on another sheet I refer to A2:f2. My problem is that every time a new form line is added my reference functions goes from A2 to A3, B2 to B3 etc. ... I think it's because the way google form inserts the data so it's not filling but inserts a new line. I've tried to fix my references with $A$2 for example but it didn't helped. Does anyone have any idea how can this problem be solved? Maybe scripting google form or is there any way to reference to a cell on another way? Thanks, Vendel

Comment: Try [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=es)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working (or i used it not correctly)

Comment: Edit your question to show what you tried.